# Display variable from textarea WP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
<?php 
    /*
    ...
    */
    add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcode_mail');

    function register_shortcode_mail(){
       add_shortcode('mail-sender', 'mail_sender_function');
    }

    function mail_sender_function(){

        echo "<form name='myForm' method='POST'>
            Subject: <input type='text' name='subject'>
            <textarea rows = '5' cols = '80' name = 'message' form = 'usrform'>
            </textarea>
            <input type = 'Submit' name='btn' value = 'Send'>
        </form>";
        if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
            $sub = $_POST['subject'];
            $mes = $_POST['message'];
            echo "$mes";
        }

    }
?>
```

Hi. I'm trying to display content of textarea($mes) at wordpress site but whenever I click on Submit btn all the input boxes containing some text clear themselves and nothing echo'es.

Comment: can you replace isset($_POST['btn']) with $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and try

Comment: I've market it ans can you please accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:
 `isset($_POST['btn'])` 
with 
`$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"`